# Global functions in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to import some global functions into each page on my asp.net 4 VB website.

Is global.asax a suitable place to write these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nops

Create you class file in App_code folder and in that create function that will be available to all you pages in application.

If you want to access the function directly without creating class object that create static function in your class file that will do the work for you.

or

Create class library and create class/function in it and that make use of that library in your project that will also allow you to access that class library function in all your page class files.

Comment: Ah great thanks - so in the App_code folder (which i'll need to create) what do i name the file? .aspx.vb, .vb, .class?

Comment: @DarkcatStudios - Add class file over there , click on solution and click add classfile that will do work for you..